# Gap between validation loss and training loss

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Below is a plot of validation loss and training loss for my CNN model.

The validation loss is decreasing with training loss but there is a gap between the two functions.

What does this mean? The model is not overfitting as the validation loss is decreasing, but is something wrong with the model as there is a gap between the two functions?

I'm new to this, so please help.

[image: Validation loss]

Answer (score 1):

Overfitting is not necessarily accompanied by the flattening of the validation loss curve - the gap between the loss curves simply indicates that the model is learning relationships that do not apply to the validation data. The first thing I would check in such a scenario is the balance of the sets - do both training and validation sets comprise of an equal distribution of classes/values? Was the entire dataset properly shuffled before assigning 'training' and 'validation' tags to them?

Comment: I'm using two sessions from the same dataset. The first session is used for training the model and the second for validation. The first session used for training is split into a training set and testing set of ration 0.33 using the sklearn train_test_split with the random state. Should I shuffle the data I'm using for validation as well?

Comment: Do you mean that you are randomly selecting a certain fraction from the dataset for training, and then randomly selecting again from the same dataset for validation? Those validation results will not be very useful, since it is likely that at least some of the data used in training will be selected again for validation. The right thing to do would be to split the data first, train on one part of the split, and validate on the other.

Comment: The aim of this work is to classify EEG signals. The data is acquired from an experiment conducted in several sessions. The training is done using the first session and the validation is done using another session from the same experiment. is. The validation is therefore done using unseen data but the same type of data. When training the model, the data from session one was shuffled before splitting into traning and test set. When validating the model using unseen data from session two, the data was not shuffled.